# Client side validation only half works, works for a textarea, not a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, client-side

Let me start by explaining my situation.  Right now the server side validation for my form works, and now I am trying to get the client side validation working for my form.  Currently my form has both textboxs and a textarea, but only the text area is using the client side validation, none of my textboxs are.  If I hit the submit button, using fiddler I can see it is still calling the server to validate the form.  Can anyone please help me understand why the client side validation will work for my textarea, but won't work for my textboxs.  I am very new to asp.net and C# so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have looked on several sites so far for help:

[MVC 2 Client side validation is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949831/mvc-2-client-side-validation-is-not-working)

Client side validation - Pietro Brambati's Blog

Haacked.com - MVC 2 Custom Validation

Scott Gu's Blog - Model Validation

and several others which I just have already closed the tabs on.  I apologize for not being able to make them all links, but since this is my first post, I am only allowed one link.  Here is my code,

From the master page:

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

From the Form:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HaveAQuestion.ascx.cs"
Inherits="ViewUserControl<HaveAQuestionViewModel>" %>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<div id="HaveAQuestion">
<%--<form method="post" action="<%= Url.Action("SendMessage", "Home") %>">--%>
<%using (Html.BeginForm("SendMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
  {%>
<fieldset id="signin_menu" <% if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {%>
    style="display: block;"
<%} %> >
    <div style="padding: 25px">
        <div class="FieldTitle">
            First & Last Name
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Name)%>
            </div>
        <div class="FieldArea">
            <%--<input id="username" name="username" value="" class="Fields" title="username" type="text">--%>
            <%= Html.TextBox("name", Model.Name, new { id = "name", title = "name", @class = "Fields" })%>
        </div>
        <div class="FieldTitle">
            Phone
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Phone)%>
            </div>
        <div class="FieldArea">
            <%--<input id="username" name="username" value="" class="Fields" title="username" type="text">--%>
            <%= Html.TextBox("phone", Model.Phone, new { id = "phone", title = "phone", @class = "Fields" })%>
        </div>
        <div class="FieldTitle">
            Email
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Email)%>
         </div>
        <div class="FieldArea">
            <%--<input id="username" name="username" value="" class="Fields" title="username" type="text">--%>
            <%= Html.TextBox("email", Model.Email, new { id = "email", title = "email", @class = "Fields" })%>
        </div>
        <div class="FieldTitle">
            Comments/Questions
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.CommentsOrQuestions)%>
            </div>
        <div class="TextArea">
            <%= Html.TextArea("CommentsOrQuestions", Model.CommentsOrQuestions, 4, 100, new { id = "CommentsOrQuestions", title = "comments", @class = "TextAreaField" })%>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 10px">           
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("error")%>
            <% if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
               {%><br /><%} %>                
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
<%--</form>--%>
```

The View Model Code (As you can see the first [Required] tag has AllowEmptyString in it which I had read from a different article, and to show you that I have tested it):

```
public class HaveAQuestionViewModel
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    //this is my own regular expression that I created
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\.a-zA-Z0-9_]*[@][.a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]([a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "*")]

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    // Will take ddd-ddd-dddd or (ddd)ddd-dddd, or (ddd)-ddd-dddd
    [RegularExpression("[(]*([0-9]{3})[)]*[-]*([0-9]{3})[-]([0-9]{4})$" , ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public string CommentsOrQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller (this doesn't matter because it is suppose to validate everything on the client side.

The script being produced from <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) 
{ window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }
window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push(
{"Fields":[{"FieldName":"Name","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,
"ValidationMessageId":"Name_validationMessage",
"ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"*","ValidationParameters":    },"ValidationType":"required"}]},
{"FieldName":"Phone","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,
"ValidationMessageId":"Phone_validationMessage",
"ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"*","ValidationParameters":{"pattern":"[(]*([0-9]  {3})[)]*[-]*([0-9]{3})[-]([0-9]{4})$"},
"ValidationType":"regularExpression"},
{"ErrorMessage":"*","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]},
{"FieldName":"Email","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,
"ValidationMessageId":"Email_validationMessage",
"ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"*","ValidationParameters":{"pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\.a-zA-Z0-9_]*[@][.a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]([a-z]{2,4})$"},
"ValidationType":"regularExpression"},{"ErrorMessage":"*","ValidationParameters":{},
"ValidationType":"required"}]},
{"FieldName":"CommentsOrQuestions","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,
"ValidationMessageId":"CommentsOrQuestions_validationMessage",
"ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"*","ValidationParameters": {},"ValidationType":"required"}]},
{"FieldName":"error","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,
"ValidationMessageId":"error_validationMessage","ValidationRules":  []}],"FormId":"form0","ReplaceValidationSummary":false});
//]]>
</script>
```

Please help me, I'm running VS 2010, and using ASP.NET MVC 2.0.  For some reason the text area will work while none of my text boxes do.

Comment: I have Microsoft creating the javascript from it's RegEx, so wouldn't ASP.NET be able to do any conversions if necessary?  I can't tell you if it is, or not, but the name field does not have a RegEx expression being used, and it has the same problem as my other 2 text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capitalizing the id of each texbox.

Comment: Yeah, it's the name of the Textboxes.  If Html.TextBoxFor was used, it would have used the exact name of the model's property, and then the validation would work.

Comment: I tried capitalizing the id of each text box ID = "EMAIL etc. with no success :-(  The reason I'm using textboxers is to keep the design of the page.

Comment: LOL, I meant "Email" so that it matches your validation statements.